# S3 Notification - Downloadable Link

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that requires the URL associated with an S3 object.

I have S3 notifications set-up as described, and have looked over the template for a Record https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html

My question is, is there a way to determine the URL Link for an object? (assumes client has read permissions)

Is it safe to use the pattern:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/{bucket name}/{key}

And/Or is there a better way of obtaining information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not safe to use `https://s3.amazonaws.com/{bucket}/{key}`.

That is only valid for objects in the us-east-1 region -- the original S3 region -- and only for ipv4.  Requests for buckets in other regions will throw an error except in a few limited circumstances.

The standardized formats:

```
https://{bucket}.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/{key} # ipv4
https://{bucket}.s3.dualstack.{region}.amazonaws.com/{key} # ipv4/v6
```

If the bucket has dots in its name, place the bucket name between the hostname and key, `...amazonaws.com/{bucket}/{key}`, instead of at the beginning of the hostname.

Some regions also have legacy hostnames that are also valid, such as replacing `s3.us-west-2` with `s3-us-west-2` in us-west-2, or replacing `s3.us-east-1` with `s3-external-1` in us-east-1 but all regions now support the consistent formats, above.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region